# Java - Compare Strings with equals but says type mismatch string-bool

Tags: java, string, types, compare, mismatch

I just want to compare two strings with each other in line 5 in the posted code but it says: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean.

but both of them are strings or strings in an array. What is the problem here?
This is my Code:

```
final int ObjektlängeForActionListener = ProjektOBjektlängeGlobal;
comboBox_projekt.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for(int key = 0; key < ObjektlängeForActionListener; key++){
      if((String)comboBox_projekt.getSelectedItem().equals(Projektname0JSON[key])){
        if(Verrechenbar0JSON[key] == "1"){
          check_verrechenbar.setSelected(true); 
        }
        if(Verrechenbar0JSON[key] == "0"){
          check_verrechenbar.setSelected(false);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks for the help beforehand :)

Comment: Your cast is in the wrong place. You're trying to cast the result of `equals` to a `String` - which obviously doesn't work. Why do you feel you need to cast anyway?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the error is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to String." rather than the other way around like you posted.

Comment: Small hint: write your code in English (regardless of your native language) - it helps when asking others for help. Also you should avoid using non-standard ASCII symbols for your identifiers, it can easily lead to errors when trying to compile the code on another machine

Comment: @Erwin i copy pasted the error so its like i wrote. Removed the cast and works fine thanks!

Comment: @ UnholySheep Oke thanks for the tip. Im in a small company and the program is actually just for intern use so it doesnt really matter but yeah you are right and i will try to do it :)

Comment: You are doing object comparison (`==`) on strings (`Verrechenbar0JSON[key] == "0"`). Please don't. Always use `equals` when comparing strings.

Comment: @Tobb Jep was wrong too. But fixed it already and yes thanks, will look out for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cast the result of `equals` to a `String`. Remove the cast or cast `comboBox_projekt.getSelectedItem()` to a `String`

```
if(comboBox_projekt.getSelectedItem().equals(Projektname0JSON[key])){
```

or

```
if(((String)comboBox_projekt.getSelectedItem()).equals(Projektname0JSON[key])){
```